# Applying Newton's Law on a system

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

[image: 1]

While learning about applying Newton's Law on a system , my teacher drew the FBD of the three block system as follows:

[image: 2]

But why must we must include tension forces on blocks. When applying newton's law on a system, we need to consider only external forces on the system and there we must include here weight of system, the reaction force and the force $F$.

Am I wrong in above statement?

When we say we consider three bocks as a system, do we also include the string in that system?

Also this posed another question to me: Why do we consider only external forces on the system while applying Newton's law?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what you define as your "system".

If you take the combination of all 3 blocks + string as your system then yes you need not write the tensional forces as they are internal forces.

In your diagram you are considering every block seperately as a "system" and drawing the FBD for it. That would be necessary if you wanted to know the tensional forces in such a case

Comment: If tensional forces are internal forces why do we not write them

Comment: @lalittolani You can write them but they would  cancel out anyway in action-reaction pairs

Comment: But why should we write them when we understand that  tensional force on A will not have impact on deciding the motion of system as whole

Comment: @lalittolani Do you wish to find the tensional forces here? If not you needn't write them

Comment: Is the acceleration of complete system same as acceleration of COM of system?

Comment: Here yes as all parts move with the same acceleration  (unless the string can stretch). In general this doesn't make much sense because different parts of the system can move with different accelerations (and different directions )

Comment: Can you clear my one more confusion

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127101/discussion-between-lalit-tolani-and-vamsi-krishna).